# Visual Studio. How to make a step into in one of previous frames of callstack?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

It drives me crazy. Why can't I navigate using step forward or into in callstack frames? It works only with the current frame (if you try to step into in a previous frame it will switch you to the step into of the current one)

So there's some code executed, I don't want to reexecute it or change execution line or switch to external files, the only thing I want to do is to navigate through already executed functions of my code in the callstack. Breakpoints and step into doesn't help, and I can't switch the frame to the needed, because not all calls are shown in the callstack, it includes only high level calls, but it doesn't include second or third depth level calls, even if it is not in the external code, but in my own.
I need to reexecute the program 100 times because of this and how will it be possible to navigate through a dump file with this VS flaw?
I'm working with Qt/C++ and few C++ 20 modules, but I think there will be the same behavior of VS in other projects. By the way I was said that GDB debugger works fine with steps into in callstack, thus only MSVC debugger has such a problem.

Here's the video capture of the problem - I try do step forward in the frame with tryMove(), but I step forward in countParticular() (the newest frame):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oFpTw-9z-VjWz25pn8ahfDMvuyi8FAvq/view?usp=drive_link
Here's a link if you are not authorised in google drive:
https://imgur.com/TVXOLUR
And if you will pause the video you will also see, that VirtualBoard::halfMove() was actually executed but it doesn't appear in the callstack though there're no VS optimizations turned on.

Here's a little bit simplified sample of the code used in the video, it is a recursion for testing chess moves by counting them:
https://pastebin.com/WCvygTXe
I want to navigate through tryMove() method or to step into some of the calls made by tryMove(), but the debugger switches me to countParticular() method in the latest callstack frame:

The method I want to navigate through:

```
unsigned VirtualValidator::tryMove(int depth, int i, scoord from, scoord to, char promo)
{
    halfmove last_move;
    board->VirtualBoard::halfMove(from, to, promo, last_move); 
// HERE: i want to step into this function for example
    unsigned move_count = countMoves(depth, i);
    board->VirtualBoard::revertHalfmove(last_move); 
// HERE: or into this one, or just skip it and use step over
    return move_count;
}
```

The method I am switched to:

```
unsigned VirtualValidator::countParticular(int depth, int i, scoord from) 
{
    scoord last_from;
    scoord last_to;
    if (board->history.size() > 16) {
        last_from = board->history[16].move.first.coord;
        last_to = board->history[16].move.second.coord;
    }
    scoord next_from_last;
    scoord next_to_last;
    if (board->history.size() > 17) {
        last_from = board->history[17].move.first.coord;
        last_to = board->history[17].move.second.coord;
    }
    scoord h2 = stringToCoord("h2");
    scoord h3 = stringToCoord("h3");
    scoord a7 = stringToCoord("a7");
    scoord a5 = stringToCoord("a5");
    auto debugPause = [&](scoord to) {
        return last_from == h2 &&
               last_to == h3 &&
               from == a7 &&
               to == a5;
        };
 
 
    unsigned particular_count = 0;
    set<scoord> saved_moves;
    findValid(from, saved_moves);
    if (i == depth - 1) {
        particular_count = saved_moves.size();
        for (scoord to : saved_moves) {
            bool can_promote = canPromote(from, to);
            particular_count += 3 * can_promote;
            bool pause = debugPause(to);
            if (!i || debugPause(to)) {
                string str = can_promote ? "QRNB" : "e";
                for (char promo : str) {
                    //cout << "    depth: " << depth;
                    printMoveCount(from, to, promo, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        for (scoord to : saved_moves) {
            string str = canPromote(from, to) ? "QRNB" : "e";
            for (char promo : str) {
                auto copy_count = tryMove(depth, i + 1, from, to, promo); 
// HERE: the debugger is driving me here instead of the function I wish
                particular_count += copy_count;
                bool pause = debugPause(to);
                if (!i || debugPause(to))
                    printMoveCount(from, to, promo, copy_count);
            }
        }
    }
    saved_moves.clear();
    return particular_count;
}
```

Comment: Have you found the callstack window yet, you can double click on any frame there and investigate the scope you're (watch variables etc0.  I've used MSVC debugger for a long time even multiple threads with multiple callstacks and it works fine.

Comment: [View the call stack and use the Call Stack window in the debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-call-stack-window?view=vs-2022)

Comment: @PepijnKramer
Yes, of cause

Comment: Are you talking about when you have multiple threads running? Go to the call stack of the thread you want, put a break point on the next line, hit continue, and it should hit that breakpoint so you can continue.

Comment: @PepijnKramer it will be hard to describe by words, you just need to try using step into in one of previous frames to understand.

Comment: Actually the qt application is multithread (as I think most of them are), but I am working in the same thread only

Comment: I think I do not understand your problem then. Is your code so monolithic you cant test pieces in isolation?

Comment: @PepijnKramer I will make a video soon

Comment: It is totally unclear what you are complaining about. Please post (a) a sample program (b) where you are stopped in it (c) where you want to navigate (d) where VS sends you instead. A video IMHO would be suboptimal. Just show the text.

Comment: Visual Studio allows me click on which frame I want to view in the debugger.  I've not run into the issue you are describing.  I've been using Visual Studio since it came out, and before that all of Microsoft's predecessor products (starting with Microsoft C 4.2 and CodeView debugger).

Comment: Do you mean you want to go "back in time" by moving up the callstack and modify variables and then continue debugging?

Comment: @Blablablabla The link you provided in your edit is invalid. Apparently I'm not authorized.

Comment: Authorized or not, too many PCs around the world have been crippled, corrupted or added to a bot net by people doing things far less stupid then downloading a file from some internet rando's googledrive, so I'm opting out.

Comment: I'm not opening that link, ever.

Comment: Lol, added three different links already, even the most big brother fearers can feel safe to open them now.

Comment: Let's try another way. What GDB command would you use to do what you want?

Comment: Ok, fine it is closed now, nothing else could be expected from such a toxic community of "On PC everything is working OK for decades" people

Comment: @n. m. could be an AI
Great thanks for continuing to help me

Comment: @n. m. could be an AI please wait a second, I'll try it and will be back with the certain command

Comment: The question is closed because no one, including myself, has any idea about what you are asking. I didn't vote to close it, but in its current state it is a mess. Maybe @PepijnKramer has a right guess about going back in time, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: @n. m. could be an AI   Here I am again. I would use some command to switch to a previous callstack frame (let's say 3 frames before the current) and use stepi to go into VirtualBoard::halfMove() called from VirtualValidator::tryMove()
Sorry, I don't use GDB usually, my friend does.  
So, the first thing needed to do to repeat the problem is to switch to an old callstack frame, then to try to navigate in that frame by using step into or step forward, after pressing step into/ step forward you will be switched by the debugger to the current callstack frame instead of the frame next after.

Comment: Perhaps ask your friend what the commands are? My guess is they are using the reverse execution feature of gdb. I don't think MS debugger has it.

Comment: @n. m. could be an AI They don't. And can you navigate in the previous callstack frames in Visual Studio C++ project using step into and step over buttons? Aren't you switched to the last frame?

Comment: @n. m. could be an AI I've added some additional text description to the question, hope it will help to understand the problem

Comment: @Blablablabla try to make a [mcve] and post that, then we can try to replicate the problem.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you want to do. It looks like you want to go back to a point where the program once was but os no longer there, and continue from that point. This is not what debuggers normally can do. Gdb has this reverse execution feature, but if it is not used, then gdb cannot do it either.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/step-back-while-debugging-with-intellitrace/) will help.

Comment: If you want to be able to step backwards in time, then perhaps look at reverse debuggers like, for example, [rr](https://rr-project.org/).